# CKEditor disable link double click dialog from appearing

Tags: ckeditor

How do I intercept and disable the CKeditor 4 dialog?
I did some reading and got to the function that runs when it first loads. I am thinking this is where it should be disabled?

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( ev ) {
    // HERE we should stop it from appearing? How?
});
```

Or do I need some type of on double click event listener?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up disabling the dialog from forming in the first place with

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceCreated', function( ev ) {
    var cke = ev.editor;
    cke.on( 'doubleclick', function( evt ) {
        return false;
    } );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Ben's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508921/366904) did not work for me in newest CKEDITOR version 4.11.3

After a small modification, I managed to get it to work.

I changed `instanceCreated` to `instanceReady`. Here is my working code:

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function( ev )
{
    ev.editor.on( 'doubleclick' , function( evt )
    {
        return false;
    });
});
```

My code is placed inside:

`CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) { [HERE IS MY CODE] };`

which is placed in a custom `config.js` file

On a website my CKEDITOR object is placed using:

`CKEDITOR.replace( element, [ config ] );`

Comment: In response to your flag... First, thank you for editing and improving the answer. I've undeleted it. Second, because you are a new contributor, you cannot post comments. We intentionally direct new users to the answer box, because what we care most about are answers, not comments. [High signal, low noise](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) is our motto. But you've done the right thing. If you want to indicate another answer is wrong, then the best thing to do (in addition to downvoting and commenting, when you eventually get those privileges) is to post a *better* answer of your own.